# Activity launched from widget activity unresponsive in Nougat

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

When my widget (or an associated notification) is tapped, an activity is launched by a PendingIntent that displays a list of items related to the widget. If one of the list items is tapped, the widget activity launches my main activity using a standard action intent. The main activity then displays details about the selected item.

This all worked perfectly up through Android 6.x Marshmallow, but on Android 7 (Nougat) the launched main activity displays the correct data in the view, but the entire UI is completely unresponsive. Buttons, scrolling, view swiping: none of it does anything! The only thing that does respond is the system Back button that takes you back to the widget activity's list as expected.

What changed in Nougat that would cause this? My build target is 23. All other ways of launching the main activity work fine, and everything still works on earlier Android versions. Here is the code where the main activity is launched:

```
        String uri = "file://" + mPrefs.getDbPath();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uri), "application/octet-stream");
        int indId = otdEvt.mId[0] > 0 ? otdEvt.mId[0] : otdEvt.mId[1];
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LAUNCH_ID, indId);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(mCtx, getString(R.string.launch_err), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

There is no difference with or without FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

**New information:** If I also include FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK, the launched main activity works as expected. However, this is not an acceptable solution because pressing the Back button returns one to the Home screen -- not to the widget activity that shows the list of items. I also updated my build target and libraries to level 24, which is what my device is running.

Comment: I have an Android 7.0-powered Nexus 5X as my "daily driver". App widgets launch activities on it without issue. What is your test environment (i.e., what hardware or emulator are you using)?

Comment: Using my 5x. The widget itself launches the list display activity correctly. It's when that activity launches another activity that it breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mea culpa. After exhaustive (exhausting) debugging, I located my mistake. It would be difficult to explain here, but was something I did back in the Android 2.3 days while trying to "optimize" execution time, etc. Anyway, I broke a few common sense rules, took some shortcuts, and had simply been getting away with it for a few years. It was easily fixed and all is now working both on my device and that of a customer who reported the same problem.